# Check if clicked element is inside of IVisualElement (parent)

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm trying to check if a clicked element is inside of an IVisualElement in Flex 4. So I want something like "if this element is in this element, then execute function".

I'm aware of the 'parent' property but this doesn't seem to work when my element is not a direct child of the element but for example 3 levels deep.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traverse up through the display list until you hit either an `IVisualElement` or the `Stage`. If you hit `Stage`, you lose.

```
function isInsideIVisualElement(child:DisplayObject):Boolean
{
  var p = child.parent;
  while(p != null)
  {
    if(p is Stage)
      return false;
    if(p is IVisualElement)
      return true;
    p = p.parent
  }
  //p is null
  return false;//or throw error: child is not addChilded to begin with
}
```